# Automount USB as read only for MP3 player

Tags: linux

I've made a MP3 player for the Pi using a 16x2 LCD display and 5 buttons; what I would like to do next is to add the ability to automount any USB flash inserted and then tell my program (all written in C btw) so it can add any music on the flash to it's linked list / playlist.  As I won't be changing anything on the flash, I'd just want to mount it ro mode (plus to avoid any corruption when the flash is removed)

Comment: What have you tried?  There seem to be plenty of hits for linux mount drive read only.  Did none of them work?

Answer (score 3):

Under `/etc/udev/rules.d` , create a file named like usb-ro.rules, with the following content.

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="0555"
```

This will mount **all** USB devices as read-only.

If you have something mounted on USB, unmount it all and issue command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

I think to get RW access you need to unmount it while plugged in then remount it with `mount`. I am sure you can add that into your program to do this via the interface and calling bash command directly as `su`

---

If you want to be able to "automount" any kind of USB device on any port with FAT32/NTFS/EXT it will require a bit more work.

You can simplify the `/dev/sd` location by always mounting any USB device to the same device namespace location by using udev again..(restart required also)

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYMLINK+="Playlist%n"
```

This will yield (pure example with multiple partitions)

```
ls -l /dev/Playlist*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3 2014-02-23 12:36 /dev/Playlist -> sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2014-02-23 12:36 /dev/Playlist0 -> bsg/14:0:0:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4 2014-02-23 12:36 /dev/Playlist1 -> sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3 2014-02-23 12:36 /dev/Playlist3 -> sg3
```

You can then install  `autofs` which will detect the filesytem and mount it where you need.

```
apt-get install autofs
```

In the masterfile add this

```
/media/   /etc/auto.ext-usb --timeout=10,defaults,user,exec,uid=1000
```

Edit `/etc/auto.ext-usb` and add this (this will auto mount any 1st partition)

```
Playlist            -fstype=auto           :/dev/Playlist1
```

Restart

```
/etc/init.d/autofs restart
```

You still need to check if a USB was plugged in or not with your software.

```
/etc/init.d/autofs status
```

And if there is something to mount its as simple as command

```
mount
```

Comment: The problem is, I need this to work without anyone logged in.  On boot up, I have my Pi start up my mp3 player (from /etc/rc.local) as root.  I may just add a 6th button that toggles mounting/unmounting /dev/sda1 and throw in some sanity checks.

Comment: OK, I see like autoplay in Windows. That is possible but requires a bit more scripting.